# third time row is not generating in gridview for same data (number )

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am unable to show multiple rows for same bar code number in grid view,it is working fine for first two entries and 3rd entry is not showing in grid view row for same bar code number, also i want to show textbox in the quantity column

here is the code

```
 DataTable dt;
    private void MakeDataTable()
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("S.NO");
        dt.Columns.Add("Product Code");
        dt.Columns.Add("Product Description");
        dt.Columns.Add("Quantity");
        dt.Columns.Add("Price");
    }
    private void AddToDataTable()
    {
        string cat;
        string brnd;
        string cat_brnd;
        if (txtSKU.Text != "" & txtqnt.Text != "")
        {
            int quantity = 0;
            int pd = 1;
            con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["InventoryMS_DB"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            //cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT tbl_Product.strProductName,s.strSize,clr.strColorName, tbl_ItemDetail.strSalePrice,tbl_ItemDetail.nActualQuant FROM tbl_ItemDetail INNER JOIN tbl_Product ON tbl_ItemDetail.np_id = tbl_Product.np_id inner join tbl_Size s on tbl_ItemDetail.ns_id=s.ns_id inner join tbl_Color clr on tbl_ItemDetail.nclr_id=clr.nclr_id where tbl_ItemDetail.bnSKU='" + txtSKU.Text + "' ", con);
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select c.strCategoryName,id.bnSKU,id.strBrand,s.nSizeCode,id.nActualQuant,id.strSalePrice from tbl_ItemDetail id inner join tbl_Size s on id.ns_id=s.ns_id inner join tbl_Category c on id.nc_id=c.nc_id where id.bnSKU='" + txtSKU.Text + "' and id.bisDeleted='False'", con);
            sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            cmd.Dispose();

            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                quantity = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["nActualQuant"].ToString());
                cat = sdr["strCategoryName"].ToString();
                brnd = sdr["strBrand"].ToString();
                cat_brnd = "" + cat + "-" + brnd;
                if (quantity != 0)
                {
                    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvsale.Rows)
                    {
                        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                        {
                            pd = pd + 1;
                        }
                    }
                    dr["S.NO"] = pd.ToString();
                    dr["Product Code"] = sdr["bnSKU"].ToString();
                    dr["Product Description"] = cat_brnd.ToString();
                    dr["Quantity"] = txtqnt.Text;
                    dr["Price"] = sdr["strSalePrice"].ToString();

                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

                }
                else
                { lbl_msg.Text = "Not In stock"; }
            }
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            sdr.Close();


            con.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            lbl_msg.Text = "Please Select Product to add in purchae List";
        }
    }

    private void BindGrid()
    {
        gvsale.DataSource = dt;
        gvsale.DataBind();
    }
```

here is the snapshot what I want to do

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();` before the `While`  loop. Just put it inside the `While` loop.

Comment: where you are initializing your `dt` ?